# Updated app not working, user has to remove and reinstall

Tags: ios, react-native

In my latest app release there was a change in the base URL of the backend. When user upgrade the app in app store, it seems like the base URL was not updated. But the app started to working when user remove the app and reinstall. Have you run into this kind of issue before?  What could be the cause?

Comment: @Did you change the build version from gradle file ?

Comment: @Akila No I don’t believe I did. Would that impact the iOS release? I’ll try to change it and release a new version. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the cache from the old app you installed before. When you reinstall the app, the cache was deleted too.Don't worry, the app of the app store is working fine.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm worried about the existing users. Once they removed the app, some of them won't be installing it again.

Comment: Is there a way to programmatically clear the cache, say during app launch?

Comment: @magicbacon I don't know about how to clear the cache with code, Sorry for that. Normally the cache would be cleaned when the app is reinstalled or killed. It comes to me when I tested in xcode with test phone but I have not seen it happened when upgrading with appstore